# SQL With data that is considered erroneous, how should I track the results of many permutations of error possibilities with that data?

Tags: sql

We have 4 normalized tables, for description sake we will call them t1, t2,t3,t4.

t1 is a parent of t2 which is a parent of t3 which is a parent of t4. These 4 tables store hundreds of columns of data. This data needs to be evaluated for business logic errors. I would like to create an error log for these tables, but storing each error individually will take up too much space because of the large number of permutations that can occur with the error/non-error evaluations of the data.

Would I keep a byte array or something in an error table to signify which error criteria was met or not?

Any other ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What form are these logic errors in? Are they errors in the combination of values or data errors? If you're trying to record whether each column is valid or not and you can have multiple errors in a record, then you could try using a bit-mask.

Comment: Why not a single varchar field which stores which column(s) failed ?

Comment: in MSSQL how would i implement the bitmask? a single column in an error table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're saying there could be t1 * t2 * t3 * t4 records maybe try an error table with a column for t1.id - t4.id, and a pass/fail column for each test.

Something like, (obviously change the column types):

```
CREATE TABLE error_log
( error_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, t1_id INT
, t2_id INT
, t3_id INT
, t4_id INT
, error_criteria_pass_fail_1 BOOLEAN
, error_criteria_pass_fail_2 BOOLEAN
, error_criteria_pass_fail_3 BOOLEAN
, ...
)
```

This way you'll have only one row fore each combination of table id's and each error test save on that one row.

Comment: Well the problem is each table has over 100 fields (normalized as much as possible) Each field can have a number of errors. I cannot write a record for each field error into a table or it would quickly become hundreds of thousands of rows.